# Ignoring field when inserting data with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine

I have the following issue in :

An entity has the classic created/updated timestamp fields that should be set to the current timestamp in UTC.

On the entity, I used the columnDefinition property to set them to `"TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` and `"TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"` respectively (this did not result in actually having TIMESTAMP fields (had to change that in migrations).

The problem: Doctrine keeps passing NULL values for those fields, but on the server "explicit_defaults_for_timestamp" is active, therefore instead of getting the default value I get an error.

If I allow NULL on these fields, then I simply get a NULL value in DB.

I don't want to use DateTime, since the values are set by the PHP server (and I use a DB server in another timezone, both might change). I also don't want to force UTC programatically since that opens up to the code for developers to make mistakes. Basically I really want to let mySQL do its thing and insert DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP automatically as it was designed to do.

All I need to do for that is to convince Doctrine that instead of inserting created=NULL, it should simply skip this field and not send any value.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove those column/properties from the entity, so Doctrine doesn't know about them and doesn't try to send blank/null values for them. Then, either have a separate (duplicate) entity used only for reading purposes or use a custom hydrator to retrieve those values. Not elegant, but this is a Doctrine problem.

Answer (score 0):

We had same problem and we've decided to create our own `save` method in repository and add exception on `preFlush` for particular entities